# Finding the constant coefficients of a third-order DE knowing one solution?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

First off - this isn't a homework question, just something I got wrong on a midterm and can't quite figure out.

The question:

Given that $e^t cos(2t)$ is a solution of the constant coefficients differential equation $y''' + ay''-3y'+by=0$, find *a* and *b*.

Here's what I've done so far:

Since $e^t cos(2t)$ is a solution, I know $e^t sin(2t)$ must also be a solution. This means that $(1+2i)$ and $(1-2i)$ must be roots of the characteristic equation. We clearly aren't done though, as if we use $ \lambda $ for $y'$, our characteristic equation would be:

$$ ( \lambda  - ((1+2i))( \lambda  - ((1-2i))$$ or, expanded,

$$ \lambda^2 - 2\lambda -5 $$ or

$$y''-2y'-5y.$$

I know I need another simple root (I know now that it's $\lambda - 4$, giving *a,b*=2,20) but I can't for the life of me figure out how to find that root. I've tried setting $y''' + ay''-3y'+by= ( \lambda  - ((1+2i))( \lambda  - ((1-2i))(\lambda - x)$ and solving for x algebraically, but I keep getting stuck with too many variables.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the characteristic equation, the constant term should be positive: $\lambda^2-2\lambda\color{red}{+}5$

Comment: Thank you for the correction, you're right, I didn't distribute the negative correctly. Too much revision, not enough coffee. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of worrying about the characteristic equation, you can substitute the two solutions you know into the ODE and solve the resulting system of two equations with the two unknowns $a$ and $b$.

For instance,

$$y=e^t\cos(2t)\implies\begin{cases}y'=e^t(\cos(2t)-2\sin(2t))\\
y''=e^t(-3\cos(2t)-4\sin(2t))\\y'''=e^t(-11\cos(2t)+2\sin(2t))\end{cases}$$

$$y'''+ay''-3y'+by=0\implies (-3a+b-14)\cos(2t)-4(a-2)\sin(2t)=0$$

Similarly, $y=e^t\sin(2t)$ gives

$$(-3a+b-14)\sin(2t)+4(a-2)\cos(2t)=0$$

Now just solve for the coefficients.

---

If you want to continue with your method, you know the characteristic polynomial has roots $1\pm2i$, so $(\lambda-1-2i)(\lambda-1+2i)=\lambda^2-2\lambda+5$ divides it exactly and leaves no remainder. We have

$$\frac{\lambda^3+a\lambda^2-3\lambda+b}{\lambda^2-2\lambda+5}=\lambda+a+2+\frac{(2a-4)\lambda-5a+b-10}{\lambda^2-2\lambda+5}$$

For the remainder to be $0$, you need

$$\begin{cases}2a-4=0\\-5a+b-10=0\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you so much, not only for showing an easier way but for following through with the original method. I hadn't considered that the remainder must be zero. This helps a lot, thanks again! :)